# Hex String To Byte Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, hex, byte

*This is a duplicate question, my apologies everyone!*

Firstly, I apologize if this is a simple question, I have been searching for a very long time, and either an answer about this does not exist, the answer I am looking for has been buried under answers to questions about how to convert a string to a byte array, or I'm not searching with the right terminology. I have also found a few answers on converting a single hex value into a byte but applying those methods to work with what I want to do doesn't really seem to work very well.

What I am looking for is not how to convert "string" to a byte array, rather, I am trying to convert an already in bytes value from a textbox, into something my application will recognize as a byte array. I'll try to explain better with an example:

```
textBox.Text = 019F314A
I want byte[] bytes to equal { 0x01, 0x9F, 0x31, 0x4A }
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks to anyone who can offer any assistance!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Seems to work, I knew there had to be an answer for this somewhere, calling it a hex string only occurred to me right before I posted the question. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use Convert.ToByte(), you might have to slice your string in pairs and loop through it.

If you do a quick search there are many topics on this already on stackoverflow

[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

You can also look at this MS example, it is to convert to int, but the idea is the same.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the duplicate question, like I said above I didn't think to call it a hex string until just before I posted the question. Thank you!